# Returning multiple resultsets with dataentity framework 5

Tags: .net, sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using ef5 and am trying to return multiple result sets with the method GetNextResult<>() however it doesn't seem to be working.

My sql sproc is:

```
select * from Questions
select * from Skills
```

When I run this via sql management studio it returns 2 result sets.

and then my c# is:

```
using (dataEntity entities = new dataEntity())
        {
            var query = dataeEntity.testsproc();
            var skillresults = query.GetNextResult<Skill>();
            //debug point set here
            return Json(query.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

However when I hit the debug point skillresults is null but query works as expected. I am not quite sure why it isn't working. Is anybody able to shed any light on the subject for me?

This is the microsoft article that I am working from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj691402 however it doesn't seem to work.

Just an FYI My project is using .net 4.5 and I am using EF5 as this may be likely to come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after further research it would appear you have to manually modify your datamodel to make this work which is a pretty dirty hack. Hopefully in later versions of ef this will be rectified but for now I am just going to call seperate sprocs.

More info here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj691402.